# real time chat app, problem with updating chat

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, websocket, mern

I am trying to create a real-time chat app. I set up my soket.io for the server as well as for client-side code, I am using react. I have several consoles and all of them logging the correct data. However if I send the message, new message gets displayed on my chat automatically, but the user to whom I am sending it to needs to either refresh the page or reselect the chat, which is, of course, something I am not looking for. In summary my main problem is that new message is not displayed on addressee chat without refreshing or reselecting the chat. here is both my server-side and client(react)-side code, and if someone will be kind enough to help me detect the issue I will be more than happy.

I tried so many ways but none of them worked ...

my client-side code:

```
import React,{useState,useEffect} from 'react';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { getAllUserChats, selectSelectedChat, SET_SELCTED_CHAT_TO_NULL } from '../../redux/chat/chatSlice';
import { selectUser } from '../../redux/auth/authSlice';
import { Box, Wrap, WrapItem } from '@chakra-ui/layout';
import { Text, IconButton, Spinner, FormControl, Input } from '@chakra-ui/react';
import { BiLeftArrow } from "react-icons/bi";
import ProfileModal from '../modal/ProfileModal';
import { Avatar} from '@chakra-ui/react'
import UpdateGroupModal from '../modal/UpdateGroupModal';
import { sendMessage } from '../../redux/messages/MessagesService';
import { fertchAllMessages, selectAllMessages, selectMessageREcive, SET_ALL_MESSAGES, SET_MESSAGERECIVE } from '../../redux/messages/MessagesSlice';
import ScrolableChat from '../scrollableChat/ScrolableChat';

import io from "socket.io-client";

const ENDPOINT = `http://localhost:5000`;
var soket;
var selectedChatCompare;
let newMsg;
const SingleChat = () => {
    const [load, setLoad] = useState(false);
    const [messages, setmesaages] = useState([]);
    const [message,setMessage] = useState()
    const selectedChat = useSelector(selectSelectedChat);
    const [soketConnected,setSoketConnected] = useState(false)
    const user = useSelector(selectUser);
    const everyMessage = useSelector(selectAllMessages);
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const messageRec = useSelector(selectMessageREcive);

  
    useEffect(() => {
        soket = io(ENDPOINT);
      
        soket.on("connect", () => {
          console.log("Socket connected:", soket.id);
          soket.emit("setup", user);
        });
      
        soket.on("disconnect", () => {
          console.log("Socket disconnected");
        });
      
        soket.on("connection", () => {
          setSoketConnected(true);
          console.log("Connection established");
        });
      
        soket.on("message", (message) => {
          console.log("Received message:", message);
          // handle the received message
        });
      
        return () => {
          soket.disconnect();
        };
      }, []);
      
      
      useEffect(() => {
        async function gettingAllMessages() {
          setLoad(true);
          const data = await dispatch(fertchAllMessages(selectedChat !== null && selectedChat?._id));
          dispatch(SET_ALL_MESSAGES(data?.payload));
          setmesaages(data?.payload);
          setLoad(false);
          soket.emit("Join chat", selectedChat?._id);
        }
        gettingAllMessages();
        selectedChatCompare = selectedChat;
      }, [dispatch, selectedChat]);
      
      const handlesendMessage = async (event) => {
        if (event.key === "Enter" && message !== "") {
          const formdata = {
            chatId: selectedChat?._id,
            content: message,
          };
          setMessage("");
          try {
            const data = await dispatch(sendMessage(formdata));
            soket.emit("new mesaage", data);
            newMsg = data
            await dispatch(SET_ALL_MESSAGES([data]));
            setmesaages((prevMessages) => [...prevMessages, data]);
            
          } catch (error) {
            console.log(error.message);
          }
        }
      };
    
      useEffect(() => {
        if (!soket) return;
        soket.on("new message received", (newMessageReceived) => {
          dispatch(SET_ALL_MESSAGES([newMessageReceived]));
          setmesaages((prevMessages) => [...prevMessages, newMessageReceived]);
        });
      
        return () => {
          soket.off("new message received");
        };
      },);
      
      
      

      
      
      // rest of the code remains the same
      
        


   
    const handleTyping = (e) => {
        setMessage(e.target.value)
    };
  
    function getUser() {
         return  selectedChat !== null && user?._id === selectedChat?.users[0]?._id ? selectedChat?.users[1] : selectedChat?.users[0];
    
    }
    function getUserImage() {
        return  selectedChat !== null && user?._id === selectedChat?.users[0]?._id ? selectedChat?.users[1]?.picture?.filePath  && selectedChat?.users[1]?.picture?.filePath  : selectedChat?.users[0]?.picture?.filePath && selectedChat?.users[0]?.picture?.filePath ;
   
   }
   
   

    
    const handleSelection =  async () => {     
      await  dispatch(SET_SELCTED_CHAT_TO_NULL())
    }

    return <>
       
        {
            selectedChat !== null ? (
                <>
                
            <Text
            fontSize={{ base: "28px", md: "30px" }}
            pb={3}
            px={2}
            width="100%"
            fontFamily="Work sans"
            display={"flex"}
            justifyContent={{ base: "space-between" }}
            alignItems="center">
            <IconButton  display={{ base: "flex", md: "none" }}
                            icon={<BiLeftArrow />} onClick={() => handleSelection()} />   
                        {!selectedChat?.isGroupChat ?
                            (<>
                               
                                {user?._id === selectedChat?.users[0]?._id ?selectedChat?.users[1]?.name  : selectedChat?.users[0]?.name  }
                                <ProfileModal user={getUser()} >
                                    <Wrap>
                                        <WrapItem>
                                            <Avatar cursor={"pointer"} border={"2px"} size={"md"}  src={getUserImage()}  /> 
                                        </WrapItem>
                                    </Wrap>
                                
                                </ProfileModal>
                                  
                            </>) :
                            (<>
                                {selectedChat?.chatName.toUpperCase()}
                                <UpdateGroupModal/>
                            
                            </>)}
                    </Text>
                    <Box
                        display="flex"
                        flexDir="column"
                        justifyContent="flex-end"
                        p={3}
                        bg="linear-gradient(to right top, #3a5a89, #005872, #0e5152, #2a4638, #353a2b)" 
                        w="100%"
                        h="100%"
                        borderRadius="lg"
                        overflowY="hidden"
                    >
                        {load ? (<Spinner size={"xl"} width={60} height={60} alignSelf={"center"} margin={"auto"} color="white" borderWidth={"8px"} />) :
                            (<Box display={"flex"} flexDir={"column"} overflowY={"scroll"} overflow={"hidden"} width={"100%"} height={"100%"}  >
                                <ScrolableChat messages={messages}  />
                            </Box>)
                        }
                        <FormControl onKeyDown={(event)=> handlesendMessage(event)}  mt={3} >
                             <Input variant={"filled"}  background="E0E0E0"  placeholder='send message'  _focus={{ bg: "transparent", borderBlockColor: "white", outline:"none" }} color="white" value={message}  onChange={(e) => handleTyping(e)} />
                        </FormControl>
                    </Box>
                
                </>
            ) : (
                    <>
                        <Box display={"flex"} alignItems={"center"} justifyContent={"center"} height={"100%"} > 
                            <Text fontSize={"3xl"} pb={3} fontFamily={"work sans"} >
                                  Click on the wanted chat and start conversation
                            </Text>
                        </Box>
                    </> 
            )
            
        }
    
    </>
    
  
}

export default SingleChat
```

my server side code:

```
const dotenv = require('dotenv').config();
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const cors = require("cors");
const cookieParser = require("cookie-parser");
const path = require("path");

const http = require('http');
const socketio = require('socket.io');

const userRoutes = require("./routes/userRoutes");
const contactUsRoutes = require("./routes/contactUsRoute");
const chatRoutes = require("./routes/chatRoutes");
const messageRoutes = require("./routes/messageRoutes");
const errorHandler = require("./middleWare/errorHandler");

const app = express();
const server = http.createServer(app);
const io = socketio(server, {
    pingTimeout: 60000,
    cors: {
        origin: ["http://localhost:3000", "http://shopper-tools.vercel.app"],
        credentials: true,
    }
});

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;
const MONGO_URL = process.env.MONGO_URI;

// connect to mongo
mongoose.set('strictQuery',false);

// middlwares
app.use(express.json());
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: false}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(cors({
    origin: ["http://localhost:3000", "http://shopper-tools.vercel.app"],
    credentials: true
}));
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Authorization, X-Requested-With");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
    next();
});

// upload folder directory
app.use("/uploads",express.static(path.join(__dirname,"uploads")));

// Routes middleware
app.use("/api/users",userRoutes);
app.use("/api/contactus", contactUsRoutes);
app.use("/api/chats", chatRoutes);
app.use("/api/messages",messageRoutes)

app.get("/",(req,res)=>{
     res.send("Home Page")
});

// Error middleware
app.use(errorHandler);

// Socket.io setup
io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    console.log(`User ${socket.id} connected`);
    socket.on("setup", (userData) => {
        socket.join(userData?._id);
        console.log(userData?._id)
        socket.emit("connected")
    });
    socket.on("Join chat", (room) => {
        socket.join(room);
        console.log("user just joined", room)
    });

    socket.on("new mesaage", (newMEssageRecived) => {
        var chat = newMEssageRecived?.chat;
       
        if(!chat?.users){ 
            return console.log("no cat.users")
        };

        chat?.users.forEach(user => {
            if (user?._id === newMEssageRecived?.sender?._id) {
                return;
            };
            io.to(user?._id).emit("new message recived", newMEssageRecived);

            console.log(user?._id, "user id", newMEssageRecived)
            
        });
    })

});

mongoose
.connect(MONGO_URL)
.then(()=>{
    server.listen(PORT,()=>{
        console.log(`server is connected to port ${PORT}`)
    })
})
.catch(err=>{
    console.log(err)
});
```

Comment: Without a minimum reproducible example is kind of hard to tell for sure. But if you open 2 tabs and you write a message in the first one, do you get any console log in the second one without refreshing anything? If yes than you might not handle the ws response properly. If no, you might not have the websocket properly set.

Answer (score 0):

You are never listening for the "new message recived" event on the client in that first useEffect

Comment: you are right, any suggestions ?

Comment: You misspelled "new message recived" on the server-side, it should be "new message received"

Answer (score 0):

I believe in `handlesendMessage` this is how you emit new message

```
 soket.emit("new mesaage", data);
```

you are sending this data to the socket server. On the server, you should have

```
socket.on("new mesaage", (data) => {
      // you need write a handler
      newMessageHandler(socket, data);
    });
```

this is the part that you have to implement. A pseudo code will be

```
const newMessageHandler = async (socket, data) => {
  try {
    const { userId } = socket.user;
    const { receiverUserId, content } = data;
    // save the message to the db
    const message = await Message.create({
      content,
      author: userId,
      // ...
    });
    // FIND IF CONVERSATION EXISTS BETWEEN TWO USERS
    
    // If CONVERSATION exists perform an update to sender and receiver if it is online
    
    // If Conversation does not exist create newconverstation 
    
    // Update the chat history
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
};
```

you update the database and other user will always make a request to an endpoint to get the latest data.